# How can I get simple "block" outline of a GDI+ path?

Tags: windows, graphics, gdi+

Suppose I have a GDI+ GraphicsPath that is relatively complex, with "holes" in it. Text is a good example, like the letter "O". I want to transform this path so that I can fill it in completely, including the "holes." How can I do this?

[image: sample image]

Comment: +1 Interesting question. Indeed more complex than one initially think :)

Comment: Question: is it necessary to retain it as a path? If a bitmap result is acceptable it becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Perhaps a bitmap could work. I would be interested in seeing that solution either way.

Answer (score 2):

Cody,

I didn't see that you had accepted an answer yet, so I am putting this C# function here for you to see if it helps.  It has been tested.

Slightly different from the version above: This routine looks for the path with the largest bounding area, so it is a bit more generous than the version above since it doesn't require the "master" path to pass 2 tests to prove that it is worthy of keeping.

I made this into an extension method, so in .Net you can just write:

```
GraphicsPath solid = LetterPath.ToSolidPath();
```

The return value is a new GraphicsPath whose interior has been eviscerated (wow, I don't get to use that word very often).

```
/// <summary>
///  Removes all subpaths (holes) from a graphics path, leaving only the largest whole path behind
/// </summary>
public static GraphicsPath ToSolidPath(this GraphicsPath path)
{
    GraphicsPath BiggestPath = null;
    GraphicsPath SubPath = new GraphicsPath();
    RectangleF BoundsRect = RectangleF.Empty;
    RectangleF BiggestRect = RectangleF.Empty;
    bool bIsClosed = false;

    var pathIterator = new GraphicsPathIterator(path);
    pathIterator.Rewind();

    for (int i = 0; i < pathIterator.SubpathCount; i++)
    {
        SubPath.Reset();
        pathIterator.NextSubpath(SubPath, out bIsClosed);
        BoundsRect = SubPath.GetBounds();
        if (BoundsRect.Width * BoundsRect.Height > BiggestRect.Width * BiggestRect.Height)
        {
            BiggestRect = BoundsRect;
            BiggestPath = (GraphicsPath)SubPath.Clone();
        }
    }

    return BiggestPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial solution, in Delphi, that I came up with. It only works in cases where the entire path is "contained" within a single subpath. It simply iterates the subpaths and returns a new path identical to the biggest subpath. It is not a universal solution to the problem above, but it works for the case at hand, and might help someone else in the future:

```
function BlockPath(Path: IGPGraphicsPath): IGPGraphicsPath;
var
  PathIterator: IGPGraphicsPathIterator;
  SubPath: IGPGraphicsPath;
  I: Integer;
  IsClosed: Boolean;
  BiggestPath: IGPGraphicsPath;
  BiggestRect, BoundsRect: TGPRectF;
begin
  Result := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
  SubPath := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
  PathIterator := TGPGraphicsPathIterator.Create(Path);
  PathIterator.Rewind;
  BiggestPath := nil;
  BiggestRect.Width := 0;
  BiggestRect.Height := 0;
  for I := 0 to PathIterator.SubpathCount - 1 do
  begin
    SubPath.Reset;
    PathIterator.NextSubPath(SubPath, IsClosed);
    SubPath.GetBounds(BoundsRect);
    if (BoundsRect.Width >= BiggestRect.Width) and
     (BoundsRect.Height >= BiggestRect.Height) then
    begin
     BiggestRect := BoundsRect;
     BiggestPath := SubPath.Clone;
    end;
  end;
  if BiggestPath <> nil then
  begin
    Result.AddPath(BiggestPath, True);
  end;
end;
```

Comments and improvements are welcome.